# How do I use Python OpenCV VideoCapture online?

Tags: javascript, python, html, opencv

I have wrote this code where I use OpenCV to capture the webcam stream using cv2.VideoCapture(0) and manipulate the frames to simulate different types of color blindness. I am using Flask and PythonAnywhere to run this code on a website, but when I load my website, no video feed is shown. I know this is because the servers where that website runs the code have no webcam so therefore my website does not load any webcam footage. My question is if there is any way that I could take the webcam video using Javascript and pass it to a Python file to perform the manipulations on the different frames and then display the result back to a HTML file?

I am not very experienced with Javascript or HTML. I have tried looking into WebRTC but I have been confused with it. Thank you.